# Remove duplicate rows based on content of three different columns

Tags: r, python-3.x

I would like to remove duplicate rows from my data frame based on the content from three other columns.

```
   name   col1  col2  col3
1  BOB    HIGH  NO    1
2  BOB    MID   NO    1
3  BILL   MID   YES   2
4  BILL   MID   NO    3
5  KAREN  LOW   YES   7.5
6  KAREN  LOW   YES   10
7  STEVE  LOW   NO    1
8  STEVE  LOW   NO    1
9  PETE   LOW   NO    -4
10 PETE   LOW   NO    -5
```

From this I want to select on col1 first where "HIGH" > "MID" > "LOW". If both are the same go for col2 and select for where "YES" > "NO". If both is same go for col3 where +∞ > -∞. If all three is same keep both.

So in the example would be:

```
   name   col1  col2  col3
1  BOB    HIGH  NO    1
3  BILL   MID   YES   2
6  KAREN  LOW   YES   10
7  STEVE  LOW   NO    1
8  STEVE  LOW   NO    1
9  PETE   LOW   NO    -4
```

Both R and python solutions are acceptable.

EDIT: Clarified the conditions on col3.

EDIT2:
This solved it for me. Thanks @Adam for the help!

```
df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = factor(col1, levels = c("LOW", "MID", "HIGH")),
         col2 = factor(col2, levels = c("NO", "YES")),
         interact = as.character(interaction(c(col1), c(col2))),
         rank = dense_rank(desc(interact))) %>% 
  filter(rank == min(rank)) %>%
  filter(col3 == max(col3)) %>%
  select(-c(interact, rank))
```

Comment: Seems like a simple 'arrange()' then 'x[!duplicated(x)]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data:**

```r
df <- read.table(textConnection("name   col1  col2  col3
1 BOB    HIGH  NO    1
2 BOB    MID   NO    1
3 BILL   MID   YES   2
4 BILL   MID   NO    3
5 KAREN  LOW   YES   1
6 KAREN  LOW   YES   2
7 STEVE  LOW   NO    1
8 STEVE  LOW   NO    1"), header = TRUE)
```

**solution:**

Setting factor levels in order will allow sorting as you defined. These can be blended back together with `interaction()`. I convert to character now so that the ranking is as we expect.

I use `dense_rank()` instead of some remove duplicate methods so that we can keep ties as you described.

edit: Added padding for `col3` so that the character sort works correctly. I again left this in as an extra dummy column that can be dropped.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(col1 = factor(col1, levels = c("LOW", "MID", "HIGH")),
         col2 = factor(col2, levels = c("NO", "YES")),
         col3_pad = str_pad(col3, width = max(str_length(col3)), pad = 0),
         interact = as.character(interaction(c(col1), c(col2), col3_pad)),
         rank = dense_rank(desc(interact))) %>% 
  filter(rank == min(rank))
```

**result:**

I left the dummy columns in to show what is going on. But you can now drop them.

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 6
# Groups:   name [4]
  name  col1  col2   col3 interact  rank
  <fct> <fct> <fct> <int> <chr>    <int>
1 BOB   HIGH  NO        1 3.1.1        1
2 BILL  MID   YES       2 2.2.2        1
3 KAREN LOW   YES       2 1.2.2        1
4 STEVE LOW   NO        1 1.1.1        1
5 STEVE LOW   NO        1 1.1.1        1
```

Comment: Noticed today that when col3 > 9 than the interact doesent work, but picks the one one with the higest first integer.

Eg. If I change KAREN to 9 and 10 this code picks 9 instead of 10.

Comment: Ah that makes sense based on the text sorting. This can be fixed by padding to the max width. For example, if your largest col3 is 4 digits, then add leading zeros to make all numbers that wide. I am updating.

Comment: This +some binning on col3 solved it thanks a lot man!

As a learning/interest question I notice that this code cant handle decimal numbers or negative numbers that well.

Eg. -5 get selected over -4 and 7.5 get selected over 10.

I left it unsolved just in case someone has the same question, since the original question hasn't been answered. Where the " +∞ > -∞ " part still remains.